# Flutter Qs :Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's where i do the convert from json response, and i want to only take some of the response and show it on my applications,

```
Future <List<PNLDATA>>_getPNLCONTENT() async {
    var biller = "PNLpre";
    var idPel = ContentPNLController.text;
    var params = ContentPNLNumController.text.replaceAll(".", "");
    var data = await ContentPre(Bill, ID, prm);
    var jsonData = json.decode(data);
    var jsonProduk = jsonData["VALUE"];
    List< PNLDATA > pnldata = [];
    for (var data in jsonProduk) {
      pnldata.add(
          new PNLDATA(
          data['dt_name'], data['dt_trs'], data['dt_GTag'], data['dt_GAd'], data["dt_Gsum"])
      );
    }
    print(pnldata);
    return pnldata;
  }
```

error message

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

Json Response:

```
flutter: {
    "RC": "00",
    "CMD": "PNLContent",
    "VALUE": {
        "dt_status": "SUCCESS",
        "dt_name": "Caramel",
        "dt_trs": "0000000001",
        "dt_GTag": "00002",
        "dt_GAd": "Macchiato",
        "dt_Gsum": "22500",
        "dt_Urs" : "22212",
        },
}
```

PNLDATA class

```
class PNLDATA {
  final String dt_name;
  final String dt_trs;
  final String dt_GTag;
  final String dt_GAd;
  final String dt_Gsum;

  PNLDATA(this. dt_name, this. dt_trs, this.dt_GTag,this.dt_dt_GAd,this.dt_Gsum);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your json response?

Comment: sure wait ill update the Qs

Comment: Also your `PNLDDATA` class andyour `pnldata` method

Comment: You can't iterate the `Map` `jsonProduk` through the for loop like you are doing

Comment: Oh true. Your  `data` is of type `Map`. So you can't use a for loop for that

Comment: then what should i do? @Cavitedev

Comment: Your response is not a List?

Comment: its a Map @quoci

Comment: Does that json contain multiple values or will always return 1 value. Why are you returning a `List` I don't know what does the app do so I need to know which solution you require

Comment: so theres only 1 Value, and i want to use whats inside it @Cavitedev

Comment: What does your `pnldata` method?

Comment: PNLDATA with caps lock is a class

Comment: After your for loop you call `pnldata(...)`

Comment: its `pnldata.add(...)` @quoci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see some errors. First of all you are getting a `Map` value at `jsonProduk` and iterating it. You need to iterate through a `List`.

If you want to return a single value as the json will always contain 1 value you can try this code:

```dart
Future<PNLDATA> _getPNLCONTENT() async {
    var biller = "PNLpre";
    var idPel = ContentPNLController.text;
    var params = ContentPNLNumController.text.replaceAll(".", "");
    var data = await ContentPre(Bill, ID, prm);
    var jsonData = json.decode(data);
    var jsonProduk = jsonData["VALUE"];
    final PNLDATA pnldata =
          new PNLDATA(
          jsonData['dt_name'] as String,
          jsonData['dt_trs'] as String,
          jsonData['dt_GTag'] as String,
          jsonData['dt_GAd'] as String,
          jsonData["dt_Gsum"] as String); 
// I think this map requires explicit casting. You can check to see if it doesn't work without the casting
      
    print(pnldata);
    return pnldata;
  }
```

If you want to return a list you should probably save a json with a list structure.
Something like this:

```json
{
      "RC": "00",
      "CMD": "PNLContent",
      "VALUES": [
        {
          "dt_status": "SUCCESS",
          "dt_name": "Caramel",
          "dt_trs": "0000000001",
          "dt_GTag": "00002",
          "dt_GAd": "Macchiato",
          "dt_Gsum": "22500",
          "dt_Urs": "22212",
        }
      ],
    };
```

That way you can try to implement a code similar to this one.

```dart
Future<List<PNLDATA>>_getPNLCONTENT() async {
    var biller = "PNLpre";
    var idPel = ContentPNLController.text;
    var params = ContentPNLNumController.text.replaceAll(".", "");
    var data = await ContentPre(Bill, ID, prm);
    var jsonData = json.decode(data);
    var jsonProduk = jsonData["VALUES"];
    List<PNLDATA> pnldata = [];
    for (var data in jsonProduk) {
      pnldata.add(
          new PNLDATA(
          data['dt_name'] as String, data['dt_trs'] as String, data['dt_GTag'] as String, data['dt_GAd'] as String, data["dt_Gsum"] as String)
      );
    }
    print(pnldata);
    return pnldata;
  }
```

Comment: i cant return the pnldata

Comment: In the List case or in the single return example?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because your `jsonProduk` is of type `Map`. That means you can't use a for loop. Since your reponse is from type `Map` you have to change the method to the following.

```
Future<PNLDATA> _getPNLCONTENT() async {
  var biller = "PNLpre";
  var idPel = ContentPNLController.text;
  var params = ContentPNLNumController.text.replaceAll(".", "");
  var data = await ContentPre(Bill, ID, prm);
  var jsonData = json.decode(data);
  var jsonProduk = jsonData["VALUE"];

  final PNLDATA pnldata = PNLDATA(
    data['dt_name'],
    data['dt_trs'],
    data['dt_GTag'],
    data['dt_GAd'],
    data["dt_Gsum"],
  );

  print(pnldata);
  return pnldata;
}
```

Comment: i cant return and this error shows  `Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'`